# How do I auto resize user's inputted images to a specific dimension in PHP?

Tags: php, image

When users input their images, their images are any size. I want to be able to resize all the images to a specific dimension. Is there a function that allows me to do that in PHP?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you need is [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php), that also interpolate pixels, (imagecopyresized does not);
In my code I use a it in a function like this:

```
function resizeAndSavePhoto($original, $destination, $dest_width, $dest_height){    
    $photo = createImage($original);
    $size =  getimagesize($original);

    $final_photo = imagecreatetruecolor($dest_width, $dest_height);

    imagecopyresampled($final_photo, $photo,0,0,0,0,$dest_width, $dest_height, $size[0], $size[1]);
    imagejpeg($final_photo, $destination, 100);
}
```

`$orignal` and `$destination` are filename paths

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/gd

Specifically, http://php.net/imagecopyresized

Answer (score 2):

Try ImageMagick, it keeps the EXIF information in an image if it needs it, among other things:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

Answer (score 0):

ok you can make something:

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/

or use something already made, i use this one:

http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php
which works a treat

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very good library that you can resize images with. It has ways to resize them so they are still proportionate and it has options to save, or display images as well. Works really slick

http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/