# reduce gif image dimension

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I auto resize user's inputted images to a specific dimension in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517866/how-do-i-auto-resize-users-inputted-images-to-a-specific-dimension-in-php)

how to reduce the dimension dynamically after uploading the file to server for a gif file
I want the uploaded image to resize to a specific size after uploading of file takes place

Comment: What OS is your server running?

Comment: Have you searching for resizing an image in php? There are lots of questions that will probably help you work out what you're trying to do.

Comment: I dont saw any question in related questions generated dynamically. Also I want to know the exact code for gif because I think there may be some differents in the operational aspect of bothe jpg and gif for size reduction...

Answer (score 0):

try this function...

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php

Maybe it's not what you meant, if it's not, please explain.